# Remove the Git repository in VS Code

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I want to set up a repository with git and VS Code, but I miss clicked and now I can't get rid of the wrong repository. How can I delete it? I found this: [VS Code vs. multiple git repository in hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63318503/vs-code-vs-multiple-git-repository-in-hierarchy) and this: [How to remove the Git repository in VS Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62317808/how-to-remove-the-git-repository-in-vs-code)
But this doesn't help me because I'm using Win10 (yes, yes I know. But I don't like Linux and using the command line)

Comment: Delete the .git folder?

Comment: Do you want to change the repo, or not use one?

Comment: @doctorlove In the end I want to use a different one. But for now I want to delete it completely and start over fresh.

Comment: @svrdoljak where do I find it?

Comment: @AkutLuna . (dot) means hidden, idk how to enable this in windows to show hidden folders but you need to enable this and delete the folder.